# Rudder UI does not load after installation

Tags: rudder

I'm attempting to test out rudder for Windows Configuration Management.

I'm doing this on virtual server in Virtualbox. The host server is Windows 2012 and the virtual server is CentOS 7.

I've followed the steps [here](https://www.rudder-project.org/doc-4.2/install-server.html#_install_rudder_root_server_on_rhel_like_systems) for the install and it seems to have gone to plan - no errors or issues in the install.

However, when I try to access the UI through https://192.168.1.10/rudder, nothing loads - just a "too long to respond" page in the browser.

Rudder's documentation is pretty useless, but I've checked all the logs I can find in the home directory for rudder, as well as general logs for apache etc, and I can't see anything logging when these connection failures are happening.

Does anyone know where I can look for decent information from the logs, in have any ideas for what the problem may be?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Seems a little pointless doing it without providing a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webapp logs are located in /var/log/rudder/webapp directory (timestamp of day in the filename )

Is every packages installed ? You should have like 8 rudder packages and 2 ncf packages

Do you have a firewall running (by default, firewalld is running on Centos7)? it should be configured correctly (There is a section in the documentation: https://www.rudder-project.org/doc-4.2/install-server.html#_install_your_rudder_root_server_3)

Comment: I followed all the steps listed in the link I posted for installing to a CentOS machine, so I presumed all Rudder packages would be installed. Thanks for the log information - but nothing is being left there when these connection failures are happening. The logs do make it look like Rudder is running just not showing up in the browser. I have the automatic CentOS firewall but the tutorial I used involved running a command to deal with that.

Comment: Then you should also look into apache logfiles ( /var/log/rudder/apache2 for Rudder specific ones, or /var/log/httpd for system ones)

Comment: I also have never tried to installed Rudder on a virtualbox machine hosted on a Windows Host, but it works fine on a Linux host, so I assume that won't have any impact

Comment: THere does seem to be an error in /var/log/rudder/apache2/error.log. This isn't appearing now when I am trying to connect though. but the error is `[Fri Sep 29 19:00:14.012937 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 27962] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost.localdomain:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`. This also appears in the system apache error log.